# ContourPlot problems

Tags: plotting

What's the issue here?

The following code

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := {x Cos[t] - y Sin[t], x Sin[t] + y Cos[t]}
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0., 1}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

generates this plot:

[image]

The code below, which supposedly should generate a similar result, instead generates:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x Cos[t] - y Sin[t], x Sin[t] + y Cos[t]}, {x, 0., 
  1}, {y, 0., 1}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm counting 3 separate bugs in this behavior - filing reports now.  For a workaround to get the right plot, omit the constant value (what is the `ContourPlot3D` of a constant value anyway?).  `f[x_, y_, t_] := {x Cos[t] - y Sin[t], x Sin[t] + y Cos[t]}
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0., 1}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]` looks much better.

Comment: @JasonB. What are the *3* bugs?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you give it a function that results in a list of expressions or if you give it a list of expressions.  It shouldn't throw off the color if you add in the constant.  The third one is subtler, but much worse.  But maybe, in the end, it's just undocumented syntax

Comment: @JasonB. before we declare it a bug, can you clarify why the example above should work to begin with. According to the documentation, you have two options: either specify the value of a function (not the list with values), or specify an equality constraint. The examples in the OP are neither one nor the other. Shouldn't OP use `ListContourPlot3D` instead?

Comment: @Stitch I think the main bug here is that `ContouPlot3D` gives a bad plot rather than an error message, since the syntax is wrong.  But since it doesn't do that, it exposes other issues, which should be fixed.  `ListContourPlot3D` isn't right either, since it wants an array of numbers, not a list of functions.  It isn't entirely clear what OP wanted to get from this input.

Comment: @Stitch If you look in the docs, in the section under Applications, you see that they also accept a list of equalities, which is probably at the heart of the matter.

Comment: @JasonB. That makes sense, I think the usage has to be restricted and all the other inputs rejected.